# Route Name Prefix: Why can't I use "admin.home" in Laravel 9 in grouped routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

```
Route::group(['controller' => AdminController::class, 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index')->name('home');
});
```

This is what I'm using, based on about 20-25 searches it should work, so I should be able to reach a route by using `route('admin.home')` in blade. However it says that `admin.home` is not defined.

Why is `"as"` nor the `"prefix"` not working? I honestly don't get it, I literally copy-pasted an "accepted answer"'s code and it still doesn't work...

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` and see how the route is registered

Comment: In addition to what @lagbox said, if you are caching the routes, you have either to recache them (`php artisan route:cache`) or just don't (`php artisan route:clear`) on development

Comment: It depends on laravel version. In different versions, different parameters were introduced/removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Solution

```php
Route::name('admin.')
    ->controller(AdminController::class)
    ->prefix('admin')
    ->group(function () {
        // Matches the "/admin" URL
        // with route name "admin.home" 
        // pointing to AdminController::index(...) method.
        Route::get('/', 'index')->name('home');
    });
```

##### Reference(s)

1. [Route Name Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-name-prefixes)

> The `name` method may be used to prefix each route name in the group
> with a given string. For example, you may want to prefix all of the
> grouped route's names with `admin.` The given string is prefixed to
> the route name exactly as it is specified, so we will be sure to
> provide the trailing `.` character in the prefix:
>
> ```php
> Route::name('admin.')->group(function () {
>     Route::get('/users', function () {
>         // Route assigned name "admin.users"...
>     })->name('users');
> });
> ```

2. [Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-controllers)

```php
Route::controller(OrderController::class)->group(...);
```

3. [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-middleware)

```php
Route::middleware(['first', 'second'])->group(...);
```

4. [Route Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-prefixes)

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->group(...);
```

5. [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-groups)

```php
Route::group(...);
```

##### Addendum

Clear/refresh your route cache if cached previously:

Terminal Command:

`php artisan route:clear`

Comment: I was going to post this. I truly do not understand why people preffer knowing inexes by memory instead of using methods to declare stuff, like `prefix`, `name`, etc... They even show on autocompleton, but not indexes... good answer!

Comment: The problem was, I accidentally cached the routes and forgot about it. I never cache them, seems like I miss-wrote a command. Thanks!